# How to install CentOS 7 over a *software* RAID 0 and RAID 5 configuration?

Tags: centos, boot, system-installation, raid

I'm configuring my home server, but I can't install CentOS from CD over a software RAID 0 or RAID 5. I can only set it up over a RAID 1 environment. 
Unfortunately I don't have any PCI RAID controller.

Is this normal? Or am I missing something? Is there a way to install CentOS 7 over a software RAID 0 or RAID 5?

Comment: How many disks do you have ? You need at least 3 to setup a RAID5 and I would not install a system on a RAID0...

Comment: I have 4 disk. I know it's not a good pratice to install over a raid 0 but it's just a test!